# How to group a List<T> that has a property of List<string> by that nested List?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a custom data type that contains a `List<string>`.

I wish to group a `List` of `CustomDataType` by that nested `List<string>`.

I have tried the following

```
 compoundSchedules.GroupBy(a => a.Timepoints);
```

Where `Timepoints` is a list of dates represented as strings.  Where any `CustomDataType`s have identical timepoints, I wish them to be grouped together.
Using the code above, it does not group them and instead just repeats the `List` of `CustomDataType` with its timepoint list as the `IGrouping` `Key`.

Thanks.

Comment: is 'Timepoints' a DateTime? If yes, maybe they have the same dates, but different times. This would cause them to not be grouped together as they have to be exactly the same by default

Comment: See title, `Timepoints` is a `List<string>`

Comment: Are you storing times as strings, when you should be storing them as datetime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create an `IEqualityComparer<List<string>>` that checks that the lists have the same length and contents, and use this overload of [`Enumerable.GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534334.aspx):

```
compoundSchedules.GroupBy(a => a.Timepoints, myComparer);
```

Either that, or create your own class to be a list of Timepoints, and have it implement `GetHashCode` and `Equals` (and/or implement `IEquatable<T>`), which are used by the [default comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Two things come to mind.  First is to create a Timepoints class and implement IComparable.  Then you can compare each element of each list to see if they are equivalent.  Alternatively, you could create a new property on your compound schedule that holds the hash code for the list.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Timepoints` is a `List<string>` - I would construct one aggregated string and group by that. You can accomplish this by using the Aggregate method

```
compoundSchedules.GroupBy(a => a.Timepoints.Aggregate( (x,y) => x + y));
```

Comment: What if the strings in `Timepoints` are the same, but in a different order? If that's possible in the OP's scenario, then you'd also have to make sure they were sorted before aggregating. Still, not a bad suggestion given the conditions of the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

You could group by the joined list of strings:

```
var grouped = compoundSchedules.GroupBy(cs => string.Join("", cs.Timepoints));
```

This would also take care of the same order (if this is desired).

Comment: `["Hello world"]` and `["Hello ", "world"]` would be the same string under this definition.

Comment: @TimS.: You're right. But since `Timepoints` is just a list of "obfuscated" datetimes it should work. I assumed that "Hello world" is not a valid DateTime.

Comment: @TimS. Timepoints is representing a Datetime, it is highly unlikely you would encounter this situation

Comment: Ok, good points.  Just thought I'd point that out in case it might be a problem (no sample data...your assumptions are logical, but not certain), and to discourage anyone from using this as a general "are these lists equal" method.